# How to generate heat using a battery and a wire

Tags: batteries, heat, damage

If i connect the positive and the negative terminal of the battery with a wire, the wire will turn red and generate heat.This creates a short circuit.This can damage or explode the battery?Is there any safe way to do it?

Comment: *the wire will turn red and generate heat* if this happens, the wire acts as a **resistor** or as the filament of a lightbulb. *This creates a short circuit.* **No it does not** a short circuit is when there will be little or no voltage drop between + and - of the battery. You treat these cases as the same, but they're not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can damage or explode the battery.

The only safe way to do this is to select a wire such that its resistance is high enough to limit the battery current to a safe level. To begin, you need to read the battery's datasheet to determine what that safe current level might be.

Knowing the battery's voltage and safe current level, use Ohm's law to calculate the necessary wire resistance. The wire must be thick enough to safely carry the current and long enough to have the desired resistance.

Comment: You want a big and/or high c-rate battery. https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/what_is_the_c_rate

Comment: The published resistance of a wire is insufficient.  Op needs to know the resistance of the wire when it is hot which will be different than when its cold, or the published resistance.  They must take into account the change in resistance due to temperature.

Comment: @scorpdaddy - cold resistance is worst case, that is what I would use to avoid stressing the battery.

Comment: @scorpdaddy Thanks, that is an important point.